# How to get a String Array with one specific row of primary key in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, primary-key

I want to get a string array from one row of the primary key columns.

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)(selGrid.DataSource);
table.PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the column names or their values?

As for names, it's the following (using LINQ):

```
var names = tbl.PrimaryKey.Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

If it's the values, then the following should do it:

```
var row = table.Rows[1]; // whichever row you want to retrieve the values for
var values = tbl.PrimaryKey.Select(column => row[column].ToString()).ToArray();
```

---

UPDATE

And the following is for retrieving `DataGridViewRow` values based on the primary key columns of the table

```
var row = view.Rows[1]; // view is DataGridView
var values = tbl.PrimaryKey.Select(column => row.Cells[column.ColumnName].Value.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thx, do you also have a suggestion for DataGridViewRow?